# Makefile foreach inside if

Tags: foreach, makefile

I'm trying to run a foreach function that only should run when a condition is fulfilled.

The foreach function works fine when I delete the surrounding if. When I write my makefile like the followring, the foreach loop stops working before the first command is executed and the build process never ends (I don't think that I built an infinite loop, because none of the commands inside is executed).

```
if [ $(BUILD_SPEC) = mySpec ]; \
   then ( \
      if [ ! -d $(PRJ_ROOT_DIR)/TARGET ]; then mkdir $(PRJ_ROOT_DIR)/TARGET; fi; \
      $(foreach target,$(basename $(PROJECT_TARGETS)), \
         if [ -e $(PRJ_ROOT_DIR)/$(BUILD_SPEC)/$(target).crc ]; \
           then ( \
              echo Deleting $(PRJ_ROOT_DIR)/$(BUILD_SPEC)/$(target).crc; \
              rm -f $(PRJ_ROOT_DIR)/$(BUILD_SPEC)/$(target).crc; \
              ) \
           fi; \
      ) \
   ) \
fi;
```

Comment: What is your shell ? bash ? Because could come from shell more than from make. Maybe add tag.

Comment: And a toy usage sample could help understand what you want, a bit unclear to me.

Comment: I'm comiling under windows using eclipse

Comment: The syntax you are using is specific to bash! The windows shell can't run this... Is this code auto-generated using some tool ?

Comment: This script was provided by a tool that will be triggered by this makefile script. The commands inside the first if directive are working. when the if is commented out. I only want the script to be executed when the $(BUILD_SPEC) variable has a specific value.

Comment: Ask yourself: what program will execute my makefile commands ? If the answer is "the Windows shell", then you must use Windows commands. Again `if [ $(BUILD_SPEC) = mySpec ];` is bash-specific, no wonder it doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by my own:
For some reason the command "if [ $(BUILD_SPEC) = mySpec ];" does not work. I replaced it by "ifeq ($(BUILD_SPEC),mySpec)". Now the Script works the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Yes, `ifeq` is a make command, so it is run by make, not by the host shell.

Comment: That's true but in my case the bash commands have to work --> I figured out that my eclipse distribution deliveres a full z shell. But nevermind.. This solution works for me.